# PostgreSQL - aggregating log data - min/max time until another session

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that is effectively a log file....

```
id  timestamp    user    job     action
--------------------------------------------
1       7:00    bob     22      did x
2       7:15    bob     22      did q
3       7:30    joe     22      did z
4       8:00    bob     22      did y
5       8:10    bob     56      did x
6       8:11    joe     22      did a
7       8:12    bob     56      did e
8       8:15    joe     45      did u
9       8:24    bob     22      BACK to do w
10      8:32    bob     22      did p
11      8:45    joe     45      did n
12      8:47    joe     56      fixed bobs z
```

... etc ...

I am trying to aggregate how much time each user spent each the job.

The time in the job starts at the first (user/job) then stops when the user changed jobs:

- Bob changed at 8:10 - so he worked job 22 from 7:00 to 8:00
- then worked job 56 from 8:10 to 8:12
- then he went back into job 22 from 8:24 to 8:32

How can I pull out the start/stop times for each user?
The intent is to determine the interval and aggregate the total time spent on each job - being able to sum by user and by job.

I would be tickled to be able to create this:

```
start   stop    job     user
-----------------------------
7:00    8:00    22      bob
7:30    8:11    22      joe
8:10    8:12    56      bob
8:15    8:45    45      joe
8:24    8:32    22      bob
```

I could write a script to do it with loops and queries ... but this seems like it should be SQL - it's beyond my paltry SQL skills - even with Googles help I found myself confused!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you store hours, as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions `lag()` and `sum()` to designate series in two inner queries and finally find `min()` and `max()` of these series:

```
select 
    min(timestamp) as start,
    max(timestamp) as stop,
    job, username
from (  
    select timestamp, username, job, sum(switch) over w as series
    from (
        select 
            timestamp, username, job, 
            (job is distinct from lag(job) over w)::int as switch
        from my_log
        window w as (partition by username order by timestamp)
        ) s
    window w as (order by username, timestamp)
    ) s
group by username, job, series
order by 1;

  start   |   stop   | job | username 
----------+----------+-----+----------
 07:00:00 | 08:00:00 |  22 | bob
 07:30:00 | 08:11:00 |  22 | joe
 08:10:00 | 08:12:00 |  56 | bob
 08:15:00 | 08:45:00 |  45 | joe
 08:24:00 | 08:32:00 |  22 | bob
 08:47:00 | 08:47:00 |  56 | joe
(6 rows)
```

[Look here to see how it works.](http://rextester.com/ZJDP46087)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I learned a lot from your answer.
The link added excellent clarification! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a trigger which before insert a new row, select the last time(start) of the user who you´re trying to insert the new record, then substract the new time and the time start and finally update that record to put the result of the substract

```
declare ini_time time;
declare _id int;
select id,max(timestamp) from logs where user = new.user
  into _id,ini_time;
set ini_time = new.timestamp-ini_time;
update logs set during_time = ini_time where id=_id;
```

this is an idea for the instructions of the trigger